# Git remove commit in the middle

Tags: git

I have the most recent commit Y, the second-recent commit X, and many (50+) commits before commit X. I need to remove commit X (leaked passwords) and make let Y remain. How to do it?

I have pushed all commit to remote repository too.

PS decided to resert last two commits and copy paste sc after

git reset --hard HEAD^^

works for local rep, doesn't work for remote (after push, still see those commits)

Comment: Sounds like you need to change your passwords and update your .gitignore. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git reset --soft <<last commit you want to keep>>` then you can just re-`add` only the stuff you want, then recommit and push.  This may require a `git push -f` which is only gonna be ok if you are sure no one else has pulled/you can coordinate with all concerned parties.

You can also `git revert` the commit, but it only takes it out of your working tree, not your git history.  The above solution is the only way I know of to blow it away completely (remove it from GH and history).

Comment: I used `git reset HEAD^ --hard` two times and then `git push origin master -f`. After that I copypasted the original src folder back and made a new commit. Might be inelegant, but git was killing me.

Answer (score 3):

If you have already fixed the issue in **commit Y** and just want to rewrite the history to remove **commit X** (as it contains passwords) then you could `git rebase -i head~2` and select to squash **X** and **Y** then `git push -f`. Typically this is not recommended, but if you have passwords in the commit then I guess it can be overlooked.